# VBA autofilter on zeros that formatted as - (minus sign)

Tags: excel, vba

How to filter zeros (value) using Autofilter function in VBA when the zeros are formatted as "-" (Accounting style)?

Autofilter works fine when the criteria is set to be "**-**" instead of "**0**".  However, I am doing this together with `DCOUNT` function, which treats "**0**" fine as a criteria.  Another question is, how to make the two (VBA `autofilter` function and Excel `DCOUNT` function)working at the same time?

For example:

[image: Screenshot]

- `.AutoFilter Field:=colIndex, Criteria1:="-"` works
- `.AutoFilter Field:=colIndex, Criteria1:="0"` fails

Even all underlying values for "-" are zeros.

Comment: Because `Autofilter` takes argument as Text, and whatever is being displayed is the character it will filter.

Comment: @Mikku, can you suggest a way to filter zeros in this case? maybe another vba function?

Comment: You can use Replace `0` with `-`, actually it's not clear in question how you are using it. If you can explain that, there should be another way to do it.

Comment: You should also paste the full code, and a minimum reproducible problem.

Comment: @Mikku, description updated.  I need to use this VBA macro together with `DCOUNT` function in Excel, which treats `0` just fine as criteria (even when the target cell formatted as `-`)